# Partial derivatives of second order

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of class ${\cal C}^2$, such that:
>
> 1. $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\partial y} = 0$
> 2. $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}$
>
> (Separate questions)

For the first one I prove that $f(x,y) = h(x)+g(y)$ for some $h,g\in{\cal C}^2$, but I can't determine a condition for $f$ in the second part.

Comment: Do you want both conditions to hold or are these two separate questions?

Comment: Separate, I will edit the post.

Comment: Just to explain the answer of @MichaelAlbanese : making in the second equation the change of variables $\xi=x+y$, $\eta=x-y$, you can reduce it to the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second equation is the [one-dimensional wave equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WaveEquation1-Dimensional.html) which has solutions $f(x, y) = g(x+y) + h(x-y)$; this form is usually obtained via d'Alembert's solution which is explained in the link.